# Python Print unwanted output in oneline and expected in newline

Tags: python

I have some http / https check, if it's redirected; it assume that the web is on https. The expected result is `http`, meanwhile `https` will print invalid and continue to read based on a `wordlist`.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get(f'http://{uri}'}
resp = r.history
resp = re.findall('https:\/\/',r)
if not resp:
   print('Good, its not https for ' + uri)
else:
   print('Bad, its https')
```

What I have tried:

```
if not resp:
   print('Good, its not https for ' + uri + '\n')
   print()
else:
   print('Bad, its https for' + uri, end='')
```

The result is not what i expected, the `Bad` print will sometime overwrite the `Good` print and not stays on the same oneline. It got pushed by another `Good` print:

```
Bad, its https for www.microsoft.com
Good, its not https for zendesk.line.me
Bad, its https for www.google.com
Good, its not https for note.microsoft.com
```

The expected result is; another `Bad` will keep overwrite the `Bad` in one-line  without being pushed by the `Good` print.

```
Good, its not https for zendesk.line.me
Good, its not https for note.microsoft.com
Bad, its https for www.google.com ## Overwrite www.microsoft.com
```

Comment: Your code is broken by single quotes.  As for your question, you didn't print a special control sequence to overwrite existing line, just omitted the trailing newline.

Comment: The code above is rewritten, so i missed the quotation part. The actual script doesn't have issue with quotation. As for 'Special Control Sequence', should i write to stdout directly to do this? Using `flush=` only fix the overwrite, the `Bad` print still got pushed by newer `Good` print. @KlasŠ.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `'` (single quote) for `it's` inside the `print()` statement then you have to enclose with `"` (double quotes).

```py
if not resp:
   print("Good, it's not https for " + uri)
else:
   print("Bad, it's https for " + uri)
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the reminder. The code snippet above isn't the real code. It's rewritten for short. The actual code is working fine without quotation issue, only the print statement that doesn't fullfill my expectation.

Comment: @Xav, could you then include the input, along with the real code (or at least the for loop you are using I believe), and the desired output? It's difficult to understand from the question currently..

Comment: Hi! thread got updated to include the real code and output @viggnah

Answer (score 0):

This is how you overwrite lines in Linux/macOS terminal (can't say anything about Windows):

```
import sys
import time

# ANSI escape sequence
OVR_SEQ = "\r\033[K"

for i in range(9):
    print(i, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(OVR_SEQ, end='')
    else:
        print()
```

`sleep` and `flush` are used for demo to look nice =)